# How to use Netflix and DLNA/Airplay/Miracast

Tags: windows-10-mobile, video, lumia-640

I have an Anycast dongle on my TV. I'm able to cast (DLNA/Airplay) YouTube videos using the Tubecast app, which works fairly well - albeit it freezes on large (movie length) videos. I'd like to know if I can do the same with the Netflix app. I can't find any setting for this.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to your dongle through the action buttons in the notification center?

Comment: Curiously, my dongle doesn't show up there. It does show up on Tubecast list, but not in the 'Connect' button.